# Is there any way to make an image in HTML/CSS that is"transparent" to mouse clicks?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a scan line effect to my website to make it look more retro, but last time I tried that I think I was unable to click anything because the translucent scan line overlay was "eating" all the mouse clicks. How can I make an overlay image that lets elements beneath it get clicked?

Comment: Really, you should try adding a [mcve] to your question.  The question, as written, is too vague to answer and does not meet community guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *"scan line"* is just an overlaying decorative element, simply use CSS

```
.scanLine {
  pointer-events: none; /* element will pass mouse events through */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events